# Including a Microsoft Form inside a responsive page

Tags: android, html, forms, office365

Our marketing department built the following page and included an Microsoft Office 365 Forms (Kinda like Google Sheets) on the page:

https://www.supertext.de/de/unternehmung/freelancerconvention

This works fine on desktop browsers, and on mobile Safari, but Android we get an "Open Forms".

```
    <div class="ba-slider drop-shadow">
        <iframe width="100%" height="850" src="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Dp4vI5fQ_UGjqiwnMW3dIg4uUS9lXxZHq35wtvgCqBFUMEc0NjdJV1pSQVRQVkZJQTBTMjZHMzcwQy4u&embed=true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh"
        allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen>Lade...</iframe>
    </div>
```

Any idea how to make this work on Android too?

Below how it looks on the iPhone and on Android.

[image: Works on iPhone]

[image: Only a link on Android]